# Dynamically Adding HTML files as tabs to Kendo TabStrip

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm trying to make a web-part which is basically a Kendo tabstrip . it has a simple ul on it's own and linking external html files to each relative li using a javascript code. it works fine so far.
but now I want to be able to call functions to add or remove whatever file I selected to my tabstrip and so far it's not working .

I've searched and found some functions to the job but this one is closer to what I had in mind . 
when I use the add button the tabstrip is made but the contecturl link doesn't work and it's just an empty tab.

```
<------------------------ web-part ------------------------>
<div class="row">
        <input type='text' id='tabname' name='tabname'>
        <input type='text' id='tabLink' name='tabLink'>
        <input type="button" value="Add Tab" onclick="AddTab()" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove Tab" onclick="closeTab()" />
     </div>   
<div id="tabstrip">
                <ul id="tabStripUL">
                    <li class="k-state-active">tab1</li>
                    <li>tab2</li>
                    <li>tab3</li>
                </ul>
```

```
<------------------------ Javascript ------------------------>
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitLoadTabstrip();

});

function InitLoadTabstrip() {
    var ts = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn" } },

        select: function(element){selecttab(element)},
        contentUrls: [

                    'Page1.html',
                    'Page2.html',
                    'Page3.html',                    

        ]
    }).data('kendoTabStrip');

}

function selecttab(element) {
    var tabStrip1 = $('#tabstrip').kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    var item = tabStrip1.element.find("li:contains("+$(element.item).text()+")"),
    itemIdx = item.index();   
    $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").select(itemIdx);                
}

function AddTab() {
    var title = jQuery("#tabname").val();
    var Address = jQuery("#tabLink").val();
    var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    tabStrip.append({
        text: title,
        contentUrl: Address
    });
    tabStrip.select((tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").length - 1));
}
function closeTab() {
    var tabStrip = $('#tabstrip').kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    tabStrip.remove(tabStrip.select());
    tabStrip.select((tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").length - 1));
}
```

It should get a name and an Address and add that tab to the tabstrip or remove it based on the button.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could help.

<---------------------------- A quick update ----------------------------->

I tried to remove the buttons and simply add a single parameter to the addTab function to add each page that the is called . something like this :

```
function addTab(tabName) {

    var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    if (tabName == "name1") {
        tabStrip.append({
            text: "title1",
            contentUrl: 'page1.html',
        });
    }
    else if (tabName == "name2") {
        tabStrip.append({
            text: "title2",
            contentUrl: 'page2.html',
        });
    }
    tabStrip.select((tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").length - 1));
}
```

and call them like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitLoadTabstrip();

});

function InitLoadTabstrip() {
    var ts = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn" } },

        select: function(element){selecttab(element)},
        contentUrls: [

        ]
    }).data('kendoTabStrip');

    addTab("name1");
    addTab("name2");

}
```

right now the problem is when I try to add more than one tab , one after the other(like the code), tabstrip sets both list items as active and it breaks the tabstrip. I think it's probably because of the 'tabstrip.select' , but I don't really understand what went wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix it on my own , thought it may help someone else later .
the problem was that after appending I had multiple list items with "k-state-active" class that broke my tabstrip . I used jquery to manually remove the active classes whereever they were and add it up to the first li .
also I used to create a new variable each time I called addTab() instead of working on the same variable which made the whole thing alot slower and didn't have animation and select. so I made 'ts' public to be used in all the functions.
so that final code is like this :

```
<---------------HTML------------------>
<div id="tabstrip" style="width: 100%">
                <ul id="tabStripUL">

                </ul>
            </div>
```

```
<----------------Script--------------->
var ts;
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitLoadTabstrip();
});

function InitLoadTabstrip() {
    ts = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: { open: { duration: 150, effects:"fadeIn" }
        },

        select: function(element){selecttab(element)},
        contentUrls: [

        ]
    }).data('kendoTabStrip');

    addTab("tab1");
    addTab("tab2");

}

//ts couldn't work on selecttab because of call limited size (don't really know what it is)
function selecttab(element) {
    var tabStrip1 = $('#tabstrip').kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    var item = tabStrip1.element.find("li:contains("+$(element.item).text()+")"),
    itemIdx = item.index();   
    $("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").select(itemIdx);                
}

function addTab(tabSelect) {

    if (tabSelect == "tab1") {
        ts.append({
            text: "title1",
            contentUrl: 'page1.html',
        });
        //sets an id to each tab
        ts.tabGroup.children().last().attr("id", "tab1");
    }
    else if (tabSelect == "tab2") {
        ts.append({
            text: "title2",
            contentUrl: 'page2',
        });
        ts.tabGroup.children().last().attr("id", "tab2");
    }
    ts.select((ts.tabGroup.children("li").length - 1));

    $("#tabstrip li").find(".k-state-active").removeClass("k-state-active k-tab-on-top");
    $("#tabstrip li:first").addClass("k-state-active k-tab-on-top");
}

// ClearTS: clears all the tabs and contents
function clearTS() {
    $("#tabstrip li").remove();
    $("#tabstrip .k-content").remove();
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I have the same problem... But i cannot solve it. When i append tab in tabstrip content showing also other tabs.... How can i fix this